# How to get a visual bell in vim on Mac?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am calling vim from the terminal on Lion OS X. I want to get rid of the audio bell and use only a visual bell. The documentation seems to indicate that I can accomplish this with `:set vb`. Once I issue `:set vb` the following settings result:

```
:set vb? t_vb?
```

gives

```
visualbell
t_vb=
```

and the flash obviously does not work. The documentation indicates that `t_vb` should be `<Esc>|f` by default. It is not. I have tried to set `t_vb` directly, but I cannot figure out what it should be to produce the flash.

Also note that it does not work with mvim either. But in the case of mvim it defaults to `t_vb=^[|f` to no avail.

Does anyone have a visual bell working on Mac? If so how was this accomplished?

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to do without the alert sound throughout OS X, which I certainly am, do the following:

1. Open *System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Audio*
2. Check the box next to *Flash the screen when an alert occurs*
3. Click the <kbd>Open Sound Preferences…</kbd> button.
4. Slide the alert volume down to silence.

I just found this on Mountain Lion 10.8.3. I'm not sure how long the feature's been in there.

Comment: Awesome! Been wanting this for a while now.

Answer (score 5):

Do you use the MacVim GUI or Vim in the Terminal?

If you run Vim in a terminal, you don't have to do anything in Vim. It's strictly a terminal emulator setting:

- iTerm2.app

  In iTerm > Preferences… > Profiles > Terminal, uncheck *Silence Bell* and check *Flash Visual Bell*

  With this setting, you get a nice, big and quickly fading bell over your terminal window.
- Terminal.app

  In Terminal > Preferences… > Settings > Advanced, check *Visual Bell*

  With this setting, you get a… flashing terminal window.

I don't know how to get a bell, visual or audio, in the MacVim GUI.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I had confirmed getting the visual bell in the manner you outlined here.  But since I really want it for MacVim.  I was surprised to find that the standard method as documented for vim does not work in Terminal.app and you need to do the workaround as you suggest.

Comment: I've tried all the method I could find without success. My opinion at this point is that it can't be done.

Comment: With the absence of any additional response to this question ... I'm staring to think so too.  I will attempt to make a feature request to the keepers of mvim ...

Comment: * I had to restart terminal for preferences to take effect.  Thanks, this is the only place I found an answer that worked.